# Steam - Non-Steam Game Shortcut Path

Tags: steam, marvel-heroes

I am trying to write a small batch file or ps1 script to add a non-game shortcut to the Steam library. Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out where valve is saving the info. No luck in the registry.

This will be for Marvel Heroes 2015, launching the x64 executable. I have a bunch of brothers who it will be easier to just send them the batch.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Marvel Heroes\UnrealEngine3\Binaries\Win64\MarvelHeroes2015.exe" -nosteam -nobitraider -solidstate

Comment: See also [Alternative to Steam's “add non-steam game” dialog?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294057/alternative-to-steams-add-non-steam-game-dialog/386879)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Steam\userdata\UserID\config* and open *shortcuts.vdf* with a texteditor of your choice. Now you can edit the path.